# R datetime change from DST to GMT at 01:16 in the morning?

Tags: r, datetime, timezone, strptime

I've been learning how to use `strptime()` and time-zones date/times in genreal and I was interested to see how R handles the clocks changing from BST to GMT. I looked up a future date and read [here](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/uk/london) that in 2019 the clocks go backwards from BST to GMT at 2am on 27 October.

So when I tried the code below (the day before the 27th) it shows BST - which I understand

```
> strptime("26/10/2019 00:00", format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", tz="Europe/London")
[1] "2019-10-26 BST"
```

Then I tried the day after the 27th and got GMT which makes sense

```
> strptime("28/10/2019 00:00", format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", tz="Europe/London")
[1] "2019-10-28 GMT"
```

So I wondered how it works with the time component and found that at 01:16 on the 27th October it is BST

```
> strptime("27/10/2019 01:16", format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", tz="Europe/London")
[1] "2019-10-27 01:16:00 BST"
```

And at 01:17 on the 27th October it changes to GMT

```
> strptime("27/10/2019 01:17", format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", tz="Europe/London")
[1] "2019-10-27 01:17:00 GMT"
```

I cant seem to find any explanation for this and would love some help with my understanding!

Comment: I get the same result as you using `strptime`. But get the right result using lubridate. `lubridate::dmy_hm("27/10/2019 0:59", tz="Europe/London")
#[1] "2019-10-27 00:59:00 BST"
lubridate::dmy_hm("27/10/2019 01:00", tz="Europe/London")
#[1] "2019-10-27 01:00:00 GMT"`